# Adding old versions to a Git history? (Insert a version between two others?)

Tags: git

I have been inconsistently using Git to track changes in my apps, and I have instead resorted to .zip archives of each release version of the code.

Now that I am actually embracing Git, I'd like to get all this old history put into a nice clear and simple Git history archive, making it easy to roll back to old versions for testing and historical purposes.

How can I most easily take a series of .zip files and add them to past history of a current project?

I've seen some descriptions of how to do this - but it requires finding and sorting all the versions in order first, and then committing to a blank archive one at a time.  If I do this and record version 1.0 and 3.0, and only later find the code for 2.0 -- how can I at a later time insert 2.0 into the history without impacting 1.0 or 3.0?

Thanks!

PS: The Git archive is NOT shared with anyone else. There is no concern at all about messing with anyone else's shared history.

Comment: You can technically insert 2.0 between 1.0 and 3.0 without impacting 1.0 at all, so as to the `tree object` of 3.0. But the `commit object` of 3.0 will definitely be changed (that is, a new `commit object` with a different sha-id have to be created for 3.0).

Answer (score 1):

You've asked two questions:

1. How can I turn some zip files into git history?
2. How can I insert commits into git history?

The answer to these questions is below:

1. I've written a small bash script that should do this. It assumes you have the zip files you want to commit in one folder, and you will need to modify the first two parameters to be correct for your set-up:

   ```
   # The path to your git project.
   gitFolder=/myproject

   #The path to your zip files.
   ZIP_FILES=/path/to/files/*.zip

   for zipFile in $ZIP_FILES
   do
       echo "Wiping previous files"
       rm -rf $gitFolder
       echo "Unziping the file into the $gitFolder folder"
       upzip $zipFile -o -d $gitFolder
       echo "Staging all changes"
       git add --all
       commitMessage="commit for: $zipFile"
       echo "Committing the changes, with the commit message: $commitMessage"
       git commit -m '$commitMessage'
   done
   ```
2. You can do an [interactive rebase](https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase), which allows you to (amongst other things) re-order commits. So in order to add old versions in at a later date, you would:

   1. Add them as new commits.
   2. `git rebase -i`
   3. Reorder the commits to be in the correct order.

Comment: I don't think git rebase is the right approach here. git rebase reorders patches and reconstructs trees. In the OP's case, the trees are already correct and don't need reconstructing.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got commits for 1.0 and 3.0, you would create a commit for 2.0 by checking out 1.0, extracting 2.0, and committing that. However, this would leave 3.0 having 1.0 as its parent. Replacing a commit, changing its parent, is possible by setting up a grafts file:

```
echo (commit id of 3.0) (commit id of 2.0) >.git/info/grafts
```

At this point, if you check out the current version, and run `git log`, you should see exactly the history you want to see. You can then use `git filter-branch` to create a new commit for 3.0 (and similarly for later versions) that *really* has 2.0 as its parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you **can** sort some of your work, simply commit them one by one in some branch (maybe your master branch).

If you **cannot** easily sort it, you can create as many branches as there are zip files, and commit your old trees into every branch separately. You don't even have to maintain many branches (which can be boring) - you can simply tag them and remove branch pointers. As long as commits are reachable by branch or tag, it would work without losing commits.

Certainly, second method is a bit messy, but still better than keeping zip files around.